# AWS Lambda URL fetch data from Rapid API

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, aws-lambda, rapidapi

I'm new to AWS including Lambda (and stack over flow for that matter so go easy on me please). I want to be able to get data requests from https://rapidapi.com/api-sports/api/api-football and post the results to my S3 or Dynamo DB instances.

I've attempted creating an AWS Lambda URL function which only succeeds in returning null results. I have tried looking for a straight forward explanation of how to achieve this but im a bit stumped.

So i created a test Lambda URL function by copying the API code supplied by Rapid API (node JS fetch). I pasted it under this line of code export `const handler = async(event) => {`

So i ended up with this code

```
export const handler = async(event) => {

const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com',
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'MY API KEY',
    Authorization: 'Basic Og=='
  }
};

fetch('https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v3/players?team=42&season=2022&search=saka', options)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(err => console.error(err))};
```

I also added the JSON schema provided by rapid API

I run the test in AWS and it says its succeeded but i get the below message and it returns null.

**Test Event Name**
**JSON**

Response
null

Function Logs
START RequestId: bfb5ddd4-56f8-466a-b3c1-7ed89f3edc2b Version:
$LATEST
2022-11-24T16:07:33.622Z
203cdbbc-a661-4256-91bb-2ada34d53042
ERROR   TypeError: fetch failed
at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11118:11)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
cause: ConnectTimeoutError: Connect Timeout Error
at onConnectTimeout (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6625:28)
at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6583:50
at Immediate._onImmediate (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6614:13)
at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:471:21) {
code: 'UND_ERR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT'
}
}
END RequestId: bfb5ddd4-56f8-466a-b3c1-7ed89f3edc2b
REPORT RequestId: bfb5ddd4-56f8-466a-b3c1-7ed89f3edc2b  Duration: 194.65 ms Billed Duration: 195 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 73 MB

Request ID
bfb5ddd4-56f8-466a-b3c1-7ed89f3edc2b

Would anyone know what im doing wrong or be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your posted code is incomplete, but it doesn't include any return statement.

Comment: Related to the timeout issue, did you configure the Lambda function in VPC? If you did, then don't (unless you know what you're doing).

Comment: right ok re the return statement what would that look like? is it provided by rapid api along with the get statement?

Comment: re the VPC - no i didnt go near that - as i clearly dont know what im doing properly :)

Comment: You seem to be using undici. Have you tried this with other HTTP clients such as Axios and node-fetch?

Comment: i shall try each of those code snippets and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly it's unclear what [AWS Node.js runtime](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html) you are using (likely v18 at the time of writing), or is it [some other version](https://nodejs.dev/en/about/releases/)? Let's assume **v18** for now.

Node [supports CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#moduleexports), and does not support the [ESM / ES6 'export' syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) without an [experimental flag](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_class_vm_module), so for simplicity to get to the meat of the problem, you should use [`module.exports`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#moduleexports) for now (though do learn about the ecosystems around both styles as you have time!).

Thus the code to paste into AWS Lambda becomes more like:

```
const handler = async(event) => {
 // more code here
}

module.exports = {
  handler,
}
```

But that's not what you probably wanted, as when I test it in AWS Lambda, it returns for me a bit like for you, with no additional output:

```
Response
null
```

Why? Well there's a clue is in the stack trace in your `UND_ERR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT` which I know happens to be findable in the [Node.JS docs source as](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/7196946d7f59652c19dec278186165806b1e28ad/deps/undici/src/docs/api/Errors.md?plain=1#L13) being `socket is destroyed due to connect timeout.` but unlike [elm](https://guide.elm-lang.org/error_handling/), it's not really helpful either. Perhaps it's helpful to identify it's in the [Promise syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), and so consider avoiding promises and callbacks, until you need them (e.g. advanced concurrency like `Promise.allSettled` or legacy callback-only APIs).

So ... a more useful version would [return await](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/await-vs-return-vs-return-await/#return-awaiting) the results:

```
const handler = async(event) => {
  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com',
      'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'MY API KEY',
      Authorization: 'Basic Og=='
    }
  };
  
  try {
    const fetched = await fetch('https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v3/players?team=42&season=2022&search=saka', options);
    return await fetched.json();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

module.exports = {
  handler,
}
```

Which for me yields something that tells me of course `'MY API KEY'` would need to be changed, though should be pretty close to what you're looking for.

```
Response
{
  "message": "You are not subscribed to this API."
}
```